# How to prevent Excel from appending extra "" when I convert file to CSV

Tags: excel, csv

I used a formula to have "" to wrap every cell in my spreadsheet in order to easily parse it, using commas a delimiter, after converting it to a CSV file. The problem is that the actual value in excel is "test" but when converted to csv, it is """test""" or """"test""" or """test"""" depending on the position of the cell.

How can I prevent excel from adding additional quotes when I convert the file to a CSV?

To wrap the cells in "" I am using =concatenate() in excel.

Comment: You need to provide some code that you used. We have no idea how you are doing it currently.

Comment: There is no code to show you.  The issue lies with excel adding quotation marks to fields that already have quotations.

Comment: If there's no code, then it sounds like you should be asking on [su]. But I am confused why you tagged multiple languages when there's 'no code' involved.

Comment: The javascript and c# tag is what I'm building the application in.

Comment: So, it's unrelated to your problem with the actual conversion of the file to CSV? You should remove these tags to avoid confusion.

Comment: Yeah, I kept them in just in case someone had a workaround using those languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tried simulating the problem, but haven't ran into any situations. unsure of what you mean but here is a macro solution to change ""double quotations"" into "single quotations".

```
'This is an excel macro
Sub Macro()

    Cells.Replace What:="""""", Replacement:="""", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

End Sub
```

You can also set triggers that this runs automatically when data enters cells. Hope this can  be of some help.